# Modifying link behavior based on keypress

Tags: jquery, pdf

I have a link in each table row to view a record in more detail.  I want to add ways to view the different `pdf`'s we generate for each record, without growing the table too much.  I've bound different events for different conditions of the click, but I'm having a few issues.  First of all, it won't go to the `pdf` like it normally does from a hard link, it opens the save dialog.  Secondly, once I tell it not to save, the page won't follow any of the `pdf` links at all.  What am I doing wrong?  I thought the prevent default might stop `chrome` from executing a special activity when it sees a keypress+click, which I'm not even sure was the problem to begin with.  Strangely, after I, for example, `ctrl-click`, the page won't do anything, but `mouseover` shows the 'href' to be the `ctrl-click` modified location, and a regular click after that does what I wanted it to do in the first place.

looking at the code, I can see why it's doing what it's doing.  The prevent default stops chrome from saving, like i wanted.  The href is changed, like I told it.  Now I have to follow the link.  If I stumble across the answer before i get any replies, I'll answer.

```
$(".doThings").click(function(e){ 
    var ID = $(this).text();
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("href", "http://foo.com/report.php?id="+ID);
    } 
    else if(e.altKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("href", "http://foo.com/r30.php?id="+ID); 
    } 
    else if(e.shiftKey) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("href", "http://foo.com/r45.php?id="+ID); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Please, if you stumble across the answer, don't delete this. Answer yourself, then when somebody has a similar question, he/she can find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.href` instead.

```
$(".doThings").click(function(e){ 
    var ID = $(this).text();
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "http://foo.com/report.php?id="+ID;
    } 
    else if(e.altKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "http://foo.com/r30.php?id="+ID; 
    } 
    else if(e.shiftKey) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "http://foo.com/r45.php?id="+ID; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it by like 20 seconds.  Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the href was not the way to go.  I just did a javascript redirect.

```
if(e.ctrlKey){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = ("http://foo.com/report.php?id="+ID);
    }
```